# Is Windows Azure Drive RTM?

Tags: .net, azure

Does anyone know if the *Windows Azure Drive* feature is officially RTM?  I have googled and searched MSDN and it's very unclear on what state that feature is currently in.  Most of the information around Azure Drive is from February of 2010 when they officially announced the beta.  Since then, though, information is sparse.

Thanks to anyone out there who can provide some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Windows Azure Drive has not been released yet.

Comment: Thanks Eugenio.  Unsure as to why this was closed as off topic, but thank you for your insight.